# VBA to Remove Rows from MS Project When Work Effort is Zero

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have a master copy of a project plan that contains all of the possible tasks that I may need to complete as a part of project. I want to create a macro that removes any of the lines where Work = 0 hrs once the project plan has been updated by the PM. I am a novice at writing code for MS Project so have't been able to get the below right:

```
Sub DeleteMsProjectTask()  
    Dim proj As Project  
    Dim w As Object  
    Dim t As Task  
    Set proj = ActiveProject  
    For Each t In proj  
       If w = 0 Then  
       Selection.EntireRow.Delete = True  
    End If  
    Next t  
    Loop  
End Sub
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong! Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

Instead of iterating through the collection, reference the task objects by index. This avoids issues that arise when the collection is modified in the loop (e.g. by removing members).

```
Sub DeleteMsProjectTask()
    Dim proj As Project
    Set proj = ActiveProject
    Dim NumTasks As Integer
    NumTasks = proj.Tasks.Count
    Dim idx As Integer
    idx = NumTasks
    Dim t As Task
    Do While idx > 0
        Set t = proj.Tasks(idx)
        If t.Work = 0 Then
            t.Delete
            NumTasks = NumTasks - 1
        End If
        idx = idx - 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. When I run the code, it only deletes some of the rows that have zero work effort. For instance, I have a set of tasks under Plan and the tasks under this section are removed when I run the macro. However, when I run it for the Build section, it does not all of the tasks with zero work effort. Any idea why this may be occurring? There is nothing different between the way the sections are setup - e.g. Grouped by Phase > Task > Subtasks.

Comment: 1) What if you run the code a second time, does it still skip those tasks? 2) Are the tasks in a master/subproject or is this just a single project? 3) Find a task that is being skipped, select it and then go to the VB Editor and validate that the Work = 0. Type this in the Immediate window: ? ActiveCell.Task.Work

Comment: 1) When I run the code a second time, it only deletes a few more lines. I tried running it multiple times in a row and some of the tasks with Work = 0 still remain.   2) This is just a single project.   3) I validated the work effort is equal to zero.

Comment: @AJ123, I tested this on a 2000+ line schedule. My original solution worked well on small schedules but failed on a larger one. The new solution should work for you now.